# How do I use jasmine-jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, testing, jasmine

I am writing Jasmine tests and wanted to extend Jasmine by Jasmine-jQuery.
I downloaded the jasmine-jquery.js file added it to my libs folder and extended my SpecRunner.html like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Jasmine Spec Runner v2.2.0</title>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="lib/jasmine-2.2.0/jasmine_favicon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/jasmine-2.2.0/jasmine.css">

    <script src="lib/jasmine-2.2.0/jasmine.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jasmine-2.2.0/jasmine-jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jasmine-2.2.0/boot.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jasmine-2.2.0/sinon.js"></script>

    <!-- libs -->
    <script src="../../node_modules/requirejs/require.js"></script>
    <script src="../../public/js/app/config/config.js"></script>
    <script src="../../public/js/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>


    <!-- add spec files here -->
    ...

</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run a test it fails at this line...

```
var evtSpy = spyOnEvent('#selectLanguage', 'change');
```

...with this error Message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'events' of undefined
at spyOnEvent (http://localhost:63342/website/jasmine_test/jasmine-standalone-2.2.0_1/lib/jasmine-2.2.0/jasmine-jquery.js:30:24)
at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:63342/website/jasmine_test/jasmine-standalone-2.2.0_1/spec/AddVehicleViewSpec.js:162:26)
at attemptSync (http://localhost:63342/website/jasmine_test/jasmine-standalone-2.2.0_1/lib/jasmine-2.2.0/jasmine.js:1741:24)
at QueueRunner.run (http://localhost:63342/website/jasmine_test/jasmine-standalone-2.2.0_1/lib/jasmine-2.2.0/jasmine.js:1729:9)
at QueueRunner.execute (http://localhost:63342/website/jasmine_test/jasmine-standalone-2.2.0_1/lib/jasmine-2.2.0/jasmine.js:1714:10)
at Spec.Env.queueRunnerFactory (http://localhost:63342/website/jasmine_test/jasmine-standalone-2.2.0_1/lib/jasmine-2.2.0/jasmine.js:608:35)
at Spec.execute (http://localhost:63342/website/jasmine_test/jasmine-standalone-2.2.0_1/lib/jasmine-2.2.0/jasmine.js:346:10)
at Object.fn (http://localhost:63342/website/jasmine_test/jasmine-standalone-2.2.0_1/lib/jasmine-2.2.0/jasmine.js:2059:43)
at attemptAsync (http://localhost:63342/website/jasmine_test/jasmine-standalone-2.2.0_1/lib/jasmine-2.2.0/jasmine.js:1771:24)
at QueueRunner.run (http://localhost:63342/website/jasmine_test/jasmine-standalone-2.2.0_1/lib/jasmine-2.2.0/jasmine.js:1726:9)
```

This means jasmine.jQuery is undefined. What is wrong there?

Comment: Did you try to include jQuery lib before jasmine jquery.

Comment: Move JQuery before jasmine in loading -- ^^^ as above, same time posting

Comment: thank you! the correct load order is: `jquery.js` - `jasmine.js` - `boot.js` - `jasmine-jquery.js`